# Having $A_1=a+b+c$,$A_2=a^2+b^2+c^2$, $A_3=a^3+b^3+c^3$ - how to get $a,b,c$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, problem-solving

Perhaps I'm just a bit dense at the moment - I've re-read some of my notes from monthes ago concerning elementary symmetric polynomials, and I find that I've no idea how to approach the "inverse" problem: if you have the -say- three values $A_0,A_1,A_2,A_3$ given, and you know 
$$ \begin{matrix} 
A_0  &=& a^0+b^0+c^0 &= 3 \\  
A_1  &=& a^1+b^1+c^1 &= 29 \\ 
A_2  &=& a^2+b^2+c^2 &= 315 \\ 
A_3  &=& a^3+b^3+c^3 &= 3653 \\ 
\end{matrix}$$ 
- just to give some example values, then
***Q:*** how would I approach the finding of $a,b,c$ by some general path, which one could as well use for problems with more values/variables.
I guess,  that would involve somehow a matrix/an eigenvalue-formulation but I don't get an idea for the first step at the moment...

*(P.s.: I've no good idea for the tags; please feel free to improve my selection)*

Comment: Maybe [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_identities) is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Find the $ab+ac+bc$ and $abc$ .

The roots of the polynomial $P(x)=x^3-(a+b+c)x^2+(ab+bc+ac)x-abc$ are $a,b,c$.

Comment: Ahh, thank you. I've even the conversion routines from the set of symmetric power polynomials to the elementary symmetric polynomials (and vice versa, for any number of variables) programmed myself, but didn't get the idea, that they provide just the coefficients of the equation $(a-x)(b-x)(c-x)=0$ and are thus the key for the finding of the unknowns. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As $(a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+bc+ca),$
$ A_1^2=A_2+2(ab+bc+ca)\implies ab+bc+ca=\frac{A_1^2-A_2}2$

Again, $a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)\{a^2+b^2+c^2-(ab+bc+ca)\}=(a+b+c)\{(a+b+c)^2-3(ab+bc+ca)\}$
$\implies A_3-3abc=A_1\left(A_1^2-3\frac{A_1^2-A_2}2\right)$

Express $abc$ in terms  $A_1,A_2,A_3$

So, the equation whose roots are $a,b,c$ is $x^3-A_1x^2+\frac{A_1^2-A_2}2x-abc=0$

Comment: Yes, the last step should be given in a matrix formulation to make the ansatz automatically usable for the general case of *n* variables/given values. Thanks anyway!